# Sync Brush with multiple ScatterCharts in Recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a series of [ScatterCharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ScatterChart), each one made with different pieces of data that all span the same date range.

I want to synchronize all of these with a Brush that also spans the same date range.

[Feature request](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/3039) asking for x-axis-value-based syncing

[Feature request](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1541) asking for `syncId` to work with ScatterChart

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/synchronized-line-charts-zc3nl?file=/src/App.tsx) of working synchronized charts (notice that everything simply receives the exact same data object)

I'm starting to think the type of synchronization I want is not possible at the moment, was considering manufacturing it using brush event listeners and modifying my data manually, but wanted to know if anyone has been able to successfully synchronize charts with data that differs between charts but has a consistent x-axis range.